# library to process .rrd(round robin data) using spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, rrdtool

I have huge time series data which is in .rrd(round robin database) format stored in S3. I am planning to use apache spark for running analysis on this to get different performance matrix.

Currently I am downloading the .rrd file from s3 and processing it using rrd4j library. I am going to do processing for longer terms like year or more. it involves processing of hundreds of thousands of .rrd files. I want spark nodes to get the file directly from s3 and run the analysis.
how can I make spark to use the rrd4j to read the .rrd files? is there any library which helps me do that? 
is there any support in spark for processing this kind of data?

Comment: its not a real time data, its history data, how streaming help me in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The spark part is rather easy, use either `wholeTextFiles` or `binaryFiles` on `sparkContext` (see [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext)). According to the documentation, rrd4j usually wants a path to construct an rrd, but with the `RrdByteArrayBackend`, you could load the data in there - but that might be a problem, because most of the API is protected. You'll have to figure out a way to load an `Array[Byte]` into rrd4j.